# How to remove extra space (padding) from this animated SVG?

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

it's a spinnder icon, I am stuck at the part to remove the extra padding around the spinner icon.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="margin: auto; background: none; display: block; shape-rendering: auto; animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;" width="36px" height="36px" viewBox="0 0 100 100"
  preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid">
<g transform="rotate(0 50 50)" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
  <rect x="47.5" y="17" rx="2.34" ry="2.34" width="5" height="18" fill="#606366" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
    <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.9166666666666666s" repeatCount="indefinite" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;"></animate>
  </rect>
</g><g transform="rotate(30 50 50)" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
  <rect x="47.5" y="17" rx="2.34" ry="2.34" width="5" height="18" fill="#606366" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
    <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.8333333333333334s" repeatCount="indefinite" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;"></animate>
  </rect>
</g><g transform="rotate(60 50 50)" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
  <rect x="47.5" y="17" rx="2.34" ry="2.34" width="5" height="18" fill="#606366" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
    <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.75s" repeatCount="indefinite" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;"></animate>
  </rect>
</g><g transform="rotate(90 50 50)" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
  <rect x="47.5" y="17" rx="2.34" ry="2.34" width="5" height="18" fill="#606366" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
    <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.6666666666666666s" repeatCount="indefinite" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;"></animate>
  </rect>
</g><g transform="rotate(120 50 50)" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
  <rect x="47.5" y="17" rx="2.34" ry="2.34" width="5" height="18" fill="#606366" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
    <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.5833333333333334s" repeatCount="indefinite" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;"></animate>
  </rect>
</g><g transform="rotate(150 50 50)" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
  <rect x="47.5" y="17" rx="2.34" ry="2.34" width="5" height="18" fill="#606366" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
    <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.5s" repeatCount="indefinite" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;"></animate>
  </rect>
</g><g transform="rotate(180 50 50)" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
  <rect x="47.5" y="17" rx="2.34" ry="2.34" width="5" height="18" fill="#606366" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
    <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.4166666666666667s" repeatCount="indefinite" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;"></animate>
  </rect>
</g><g transform="rotate(210 50 50)" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
  <rect x="47.5" y="17" rx="2.34" ry="2.34" width="5" height="18" fill="#606366" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
    <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.3333333333333333s" repeatCount="indefinite" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;"></animate>
  </rect>
</g><g transform="rotate(240 50 50)" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
  <rect x="47.5" y="17" rx="2.34" ry="2.34" width="5" height="18" fill="#606366" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
    <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.25s" repeatCount="indefinite" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;"></animate>
  </rect>
</g><g transform="rotate(270 50 50)" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
  <rect x="47.5" y="17" rx="2.34" ry="2.34" width="5" height="18" fill="#606366" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
    <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.16666666666666666s" repeatCount="indefinite" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;"></animate>
  </rect>
</g><g transform="rotate(300 50 50)" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
  <rect x="47.5" y="17" rx="2.34" ry="2.34" width="5" height="18" fill="#606366" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
    <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.08333333333333333s" repeatCount="indefinite" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;"></animate>
  </rect>
</g><g transform="rotate(330 50 50)" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
  <rect x="47.5" y="17" rx="2.34" ry="2.34" width="5" height="18" fill="#606366" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
    <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" dur="1s" begin="0s" repeatCount="indefinite" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;"></animate>
  </rect>
</g>
```

Comment: why don't you use css for same it will give you wide range of customization option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the `viewBox` attribute to `viewBox="17 17 66 66"` How do I know the new value for the `viewBox`?

I've wrapped everything inside the SVG element in a group `#G`.

In the JavaScript I'm getting the bounding box of the group using the `getBBox()` method and I'm using the properties of the bounding box to define the new value of the `viewBox` of the SVG element.

```
vievBox = "x y width height"
```

```js
console.log(G.getBBox())
```

```css
svg{border:solid}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="margin: auto; background: none; display: block; shape-rendering: auto; animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;" width="36px" height="36px" viewBox="17 17 66 66"
  preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid">
  <g id="G">
<g transform="rotate(0 50 50)" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
  <rect x="47.5" y="17" rx="2.34" ry="2.34" width="5" height="18" fill="#606366" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
    <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.9166666666666666s" repeatCount="indefinite" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;"></animate>
  </rect>
</g><g transform="rotate(30 50 50)" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
  <rect x="47.5" y="17" rx="2.34" ry="2.34" width="5" height="18" fill="#606366" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
    <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.8333333333333334s" repeatCount="indefinite" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;"></animate>
  </rect>
</g><g transform="rotate(60 50 50)" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
  <rect x="47.5" y="17" rx="2.34" ry="2.34" width="5" height="18" fill="#606366" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
    <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.75s" repeatCount="indefinite" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;"></animate>
  </rect>
</g><g transform="rotate(90 50 50)" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
  <rect x="47.5" y="17" rx="2.34" ry="2.34" width="5" height="18" fill="#606366" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
    <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.6666666666666666s" repeatCount="indefinite" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;"></animate>
  </rect>
</g><g transform="rotate(120 50 50)" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
  <rect x="47.5" y="17" rx="2.34" ry="2.34" width="5" height="18" fill="#606366" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
    <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.5833333333333334s" repeatCount="indefinite" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;"></animate>
  </rect>
</g><g transform="rotate(150 50 50)" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
  <rect x="47.5" y="17" rx="2.34" ry="2.34" width="5" height="18" fill="#606366" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
    <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.5s" repeatCount="indefinite" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;"></animate>
  </rect>
</g><g transform="rotate(180 50 50)" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
  <rect x="47.5" y="17" rx="2.34" ry="2.34" width="5" height="18" fill="#606366" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
    <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.4166666666666667s" repeatCount="indefinite" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;"></animate>
  </rect>
</g><g transform="rotate(210 50 50)" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
  <rect x="47.5" y="17" rx="2.34" ry="2.34" width="5" height="18" fill="#606366" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
    <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.3333333333333333s" repeatCount="indefinite" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;"></animate>
  </rect>
</g><g transform="rotate(240 50 50)" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
  <rect x="47.5" y="17" rx="2.34" ry="2.34" width="5" height="18" fill="#606366" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
    <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.25s" repeatCount="indefinite" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;"></animate>
  </rect>
</g><g transform="rotate(270 50 50)" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
  <rect x="47.5" y="17" rx="2.34" ry="2.34" width="5" height="18" fill="#606366" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
    <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.16666666666666666s" repeatCount="indefinite" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;"></animate>
  </rect>
</g><g transform="rotate(300 50 50)" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
  <rect x="47.5" y="17" rx="2.34" ry="2.34" width="5" height="18" fill="#606366" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
    <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" dur="1s" begin="-0.08333333333333333s" repeatCount="indefinite" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;"></animate>
  </rect>
</g><g transform="rotate(330 50 50)" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
  <rect x="47.5" y="17" rx="2.34" ry="2.34" width="5" height="18" fill="#606366" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;">
    <animate attributeName="opacity" values="1;0" keyTimes="0;1" dur="1s" begin="0s" repeatCount="indefinite" style="animation-play-state: running; animation-delay: 0s;"></animate>
  </rect>
</g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: thank you soooo sooo much for helping me with me! I truly truly appreciate it!

Comment: Thanks again (from a different question)