# How to reduce the size of svg in d3.js?

Tags: d3.js, svg

I'm using a template I found online for overlaying my data on a SVG (rendered by a geoJSON using d3.js).
I've included those variables too, as they are as I just wanted to test it.

Using this part of code, I'm able to get my map perfectly, without any cuts on the sides
Dimensions (650 x 650):

```
var w = 650;
var h = 650;
var proj = d3.geo.mercator();
var path = d3.geo.path().projection(proj);
var t = proj.translate();
var s = proj.scale();

var map = d3.select("#chart")
    .append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h)
    .call(initialize);

function initialize() {
    proj.scale(6700);
    proj.translate([-1240, 750]);
}
```

[image]

But when I change w or h to lower values, say 400 x 400 then it gets trimmed on the sides, when I leave the arguments in proj.scale() and proj.translate() as they are. Can someone please help how I can scale the size to lower dimensions like 400 x 400? (By changing anything in those arguments for scale() or translate())?

Any quick reference link which explains those changes brief and clear is also appreciated.

Comment: Please try this: instead of setting the width and the height set the `viewBox` attribute: `.append("svg:svg").attr("viewBox", "0 0 650 650")`. Now the svg element will take all the available width. Alternatively you can set the width to what you need and it will work

Comment: @enxaneta To an extent, it helps rescaling but few issues: I tried changing it to attr("viewBox", "0 0 1550 1550"), this way the size is reducing but the container dimensions are increasing with a lot of white space wastage. When I change it to attr("viewBox", "0 0 450 450"), the size is getting bigger and the sides are cut. I'm trying to fit it with the div the svg is in (I didn't set any div style height and width)

Comment: Can I see your map? Maybe you have it published. If no please try to wrap everithing in your map in a group and in javascript use getBBox() to get the size of the bounding box of the map, use the returned values for the viewBox

Comment: @enxaneta I haven't published it. Can you give some illustration on how to use getBBox() or maybe a  reference link to understand

Comment: Please take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62630948/how-to-remove-extra-space-padding-from-this-animated-svg/62631563#62631563 Also you can read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox