# How to center and expand content in an SVG?

Tags: html, css, svg, viewbox

I'm having trouble figuring how to accurately adjust the display of an SVG using the viewPort attribute.

I'd like the SVG to encompass a 800px wide space and be centered with little or no padding.  I see that the min-x and min-y options appear to control where the svg sits, but I am not having luck trying to get the SVG to take up more of the available screen space (without the padding).  When I increase viewBox width and height, the svg actually shrinks.

```
<svg 
    xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" 
    xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape" 
    xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd" 
    xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    version="1.1" id="us-map" 
    preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" 
    sodipodi:docname="southeast.svg" 
    inkscape:version="0.91 r13725" 
    x="0px" 
    y="0px" 
    width="600px" 
    height="550px" 
    viewBox="500 200 600 550" 
    enable-background="new 500 200 600 550" 
    xml:space="preserve"
>
```

My example is here: https://jsfiddle.net/u5zmarqn/

Comment: Try using `viewBox="690 398 330 282"` In order to know the size I'm using `g5.getBBox()` this is returning the position (x,y) and size (width, height) of the bounding box of theg5 group. viewBox="x y width height"

Comment: Indeed, you need to decrease the viewBox width and height. You actually want to see less area so the area you do see will seem bigger. Think of zooming into a map, the area visible is smaller but it looks bigger.

Comment: @enxaneta that worked.  Do I even need to include the `enable-background` attribute?  I did not change it, so it appears to be ignored unless it does something I'm not seeing right off.

Comment: Feel free to post your comment as a question and I'll credit you appropriately.

Comment: @acoder I don't use it, but if you are using it you need to change the value to match the viewBox attribute

Comment: I've answered this kind of question so many times that I'm ashamed to answer it once again. This is the most recent: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62630948/how-to-remove-extra-space-padding-from-this-animated-svg/62631563#62631563